# What is the maximum possible value of a + 4b?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, integers

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers so that the equation $x^2 − (a + b)x + 9(a^2 + b^2 ) = \frac{17}{18}$ has an integer solution. What is the maximum possible value of $a + 4b$?

I can't figure out if I need to use the AM-GM inequality or the quadratic equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: quadratic formula, you already have a quadratic equation.

Comment: Perhaps there are no such real $a$ and $b$, so that $a+4b$ has no possible value at all. So I suppose you already have examples with integer root?

Comment: The quadratic equation doesn't give me a an answer and this is a competition problem so it does have a solution. I just can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: This is an optimisation problem over a multivariate polynomial, where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JoshuaBonet If this is a problem from a competition, I've participated in maths competitions in the past and there have been problems where the answer is 'no solution'.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield Yes it was the 2019 Math Competition from University of San Diego, the first year I took my students. They did not mentioned anything of been no solution. They have the questions but not the explanation of the answers. I've been having trouble helping my Mathletes because of problems like these.  Thank you so much for the help. I will keep looking a that problem to see for any potential mistakes but I do trust is perfect. I highly appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Let $c = a + 4b$. Then $a = c - 4b$ and the equation becomes:

$x^2 - (c - 4b + b)x + 9(c^2 - 8bc + 16b^2 + b^2) = x^2 + (3b - c)x + 9(17b^2 - 8bc + c^2) = \frac{17}{18}$

Rearranging, we get

$cx + 9c^2 - 8bc = -x^2 + 3bx - 17b^2 - \frac{17}{18}$

or

$f(c) = 9c^2 + (x - 8b)c = -x^2 + 3bx - 17b^2 - \frac{17}{18}$

A critical point of $f(c)$ occurs when the derivative of $f(c)$ with respect to $c$ is equal to zero (the right side doesn't matter because all constants with respect to the variable $c$ become zero with the derivative):

$\partial_c f(c) = \partial_c((9c^2 + (x - 8b)c) = 18c + (x - 8b) = 0$

$c = \frac{x - 8b}{18}$

Because the integer variable $x$ is not bounded above and the real number variable $b$ is not bounded below, the critical point $c$ has no maximum over the entire range of values for $x$ and $b$, regardless if it is a maximum, a minimum, or a saddle point with fixed $x$ and $b$. Since $c = a + 4b$, there is no maximum for $a + 4b$ either.